# Finding values from trigonometric equations

Tags: trigonometry

$F(x)=A\sin(kx)+B\cos(kx)$
$G(x)=C\sin(k(a-x))+D\cos(k(a-x))$

Applying physical boundary conditions gives us

$B=D=0$. 
I have another condition

$F(b)=G(b)$. 
To satisfy this condition I should have

$A\sin(kb)=C\sin(k(a-b))$

I need the values of A and C. 
Can I take the value $A=\sin(k(a-b))$ and $C=\sin(kb)$

Comment: @Blue this is the main question.

Comment: $A=C=0$ is also a solution

Comment: @Andrei then it would be a trivial function which I do not need/want

Comment: In this problem, each of the functions $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ is a transformation of $\sin(x)$ with its frequency increased by a factor of $k$ and also with a possible phase shift (at least in the case of $G$) and change in amplitude. If you have two functions $F$ and $G$ that satisfy $F(b)=G(b),$ and you double the amplitudes of both functions, the new functions $F'$ and $G'$ also will be equal at $b.$ So all you really can be sure of (if these are all the conditions you have) is the _relative_ amplitudes of $F$ and $G.$ Is that good enough for your purposes?

Comment: If relative amplitude is all you need then your solution is one of many acceptable solutions.

Comment: @David K thanks!! Maybe I should still mention that a, b and x are actually nos., distances. Thank you so much for the response!!